# submodule project not present in `git submodule status` roster and unable to commit from parent as single object

Tags: git-submodules

I use `git submodule add <GitHubURL.git>` to add projects as submodules to a main "parent" project repository.

```
Parent_Project_repo
- SubA_repo
- SubB_repo
- SubC_repo
- Sub_Problem_Child_repo
```

As I work in the submodules, I make commits within the `Sub*_repo` project (per usual, committing whichever files I have worked on). In the parent project, however, usually I am just making a single commit for all the submodules commits. This single commit of the submodule usually shows up like so in the `Parent_Project_repo`:

[image]

I have recently added a submodule which, *from the parent repository,* displays each individual file in the commit history instead of just accessing all the files/commits in one single "Subproject" commit object.

Of note:

1. this problematic submodule does not show up in the roster when I
   invoke:
   `git submodule status`
2. It is listed in the
   `Parent_Project_repo/.gitmodules`
   `Parent_Project_repo/.git/config`
   file as a submodule & there is a corresponding
   `Parent_Project_repo/.git/modules/Sub_Problem_Child_repo/` folder.

How can I get the problem child into the roster and able to have all it's commits handled by the Parent_Project_repo as one object?

---

UPDATE:
The only difference I have discerned with the “problem child” submodule is that it doesn’t have a “historySha” key in the `/.git/modules/config` file, e.g.:

```
[atomGithub]
    historySha = 1936e4c373c130860a8f92683b517dad713ec37
```

Also, these commands don't get the Problem child listed in the status:

```
$  git submodule update --init --recursive
$  git submodule update --recursive
$  git submodule init
```

...nor showing up on GitHub in the Parent project with a "@ e78c392" which indicates I can double click the link and got to *that* repo instead of a copy inside the superproject (Parent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `git submodule add <URL>` was used to set up a git repository as a submodule within a "super-project" and the submodule is NOT committing within the super-project as a single object (i.e. if, when committing the submodule from within the Super project you are having to commit each individual file from the submodule), then follow these steps to reconfigure:

1. Save all work in the submodule.
2. Stage and commit all file changes.
3. Push all commits to GitHub.
4. Make a safety copy of the submodule folder if you are cautious
5. Delete the relevant submodule section from the super-projects .gitmodules file (i.e. remove the listing of the problem submodule).
6. Stage the .gitmodules changes `git add .gitmodules`
7. Delete the relevant sunmodule section from super-projects .git/config.
8. Run `git rm --cached -rf PATH_TO_SUBMODULE` where `PATH_TO_SUBMODULE` is the actual path to the submodule folder.
9. Run `rm -rf .git/modules/PATH_TO_SUBMODULE`.
10. Commit `git commit -m "Removed submodule commit message"`.
11. Delete the now untracked submodule files: `rm -rf PATH_TO_SUBMODULE`
12. `git submodule add <URL>`
13. Test to see if a change (fwiw, modify two files) in the submodule is handled as a single object when committing in the super-project.
14. Success? Delete the safety copy of the submodule project.